# NullPointerException thrown when adding entry to TreeMap

Tags: java

The following code throws an NPE on `tm.put("dd",7);`. Why is this? I have added debugging and it looks like my compare function is wrong, but I am delegating to String.compare. **How can it be fixed so that I can add new entries to the TreeMap and it will sort the new entries by VALUE automatically**?  Thanks.

**EDIT** The problem that I have is that a TreeMap should as I understand it be continuously sorted - you are supposed to be able to add entries to a TM that is already populated and it keeps the map in sorted order. The solutions given so far don't allow me to do this. When I add ("cc",7) I want that entry to "slot in" according to the comparator that I provided to the constructor. 
This should be possible, no?

**EDIT2** I can see myself now that this is probably not possible because the map that is used by the comparator object for the lookup of the value is supplied at construction time.  There may be a way around this but I cannot see it.

```
static void f16(){
        Map<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("xx",5);        hm.put("xz",6);        hm.put("cx",9);        hm.put("ax",2);

        class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> { //satisfies Comparator<K> req of TreeMap const
            Map<String,Integer> map;
            ValueComparator(Map<String,Integer> map){
                this.map=map;
            }
            public int compare(String k1, String k2){
                System.out.printf("k1:%s k2:%s\n",k1,k2);//for debugging
                return this.map.get(k1).compareTo(this.map.get(k2));
            }
        }
        ValueComparator valueComp = new ValueComparator(hm);
        NavigableMap<String,Integer> tm = new TreeMap<>(valueComp);
        tm.putAll(hm);
        System.out.println(tm);        
        tm.put("dd",7); //throws NPE
        System.out.println(tm);  
}
```

Console output:

```
k1:xx k2:xx
k1:xz k2:xx
k1:cx k2:xx
k1:cx k2:xz
k1:ax k2:xz
k1:ax k2:xx
{ax=2, xx=5, xz=6, cx=9}
k1:dd k2:xz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at T1$1ValueComparator.compare(T1.java:28)
        at T1$1ValueComparator.compare(T1.java:21)
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:552)
        at T1.f16(T1.java:35)
        at T1.main(T1.java:10)
```

Comment: this.map.get() returns null when key doesn't exists

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the `HashMap` inside the comparator has no entry for `"dd"`: only `"xx"`, `"xz"`, `"cx"`, and `"ax"` are mapped. That's why `this.map.get(k1)` yields `null` when `k1` is equal to `"dd"`.

After that you call `compareTo` on the result of the `get`

```
this.map.get(k1).compareTo(this.map.get(k2));
//               ---------
```

which produces an NPE.

To fix this problem add some alternative way to compare objects that have no keys in the map - for example, by comparing the keys themselves:

```
public int compare(String k1, String k2){
    System.out.printf("k1:%s k2:%s\n",k1,k2);//for debugging
    Integer v1 = this.map.get(k1);
    Integer v2 = this.map.get(k2);
    if (v1 != null && v2 == null) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (v1 == null && v2 != null) {
        return 1;
    }
    return (v1 != null && v2 != null) ? v1.compareTo(v2) : k1.compareTo(k2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if I do this the TreeMap is no longer sorted correctly after adding a new entry.

Comment: @JL_SO When your hash map does not supply the number to use as the sorting key, there's no longer a "correct" order. You could modify the code to sort all "unknowns" to the top or to the bottom (see edit), but that's about it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's an interesting problem, because the requirement to have the TreeMap continuously sorted by *VALUE* makes it a lot more difficult than if it were sorted by key.  But this way of doing it is not going to work because as I say in my edit, the map that is used for the value lookup in compare is fixed at construction time. I am wondering if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears here `return this.map.get(k1).compareTo(this.map.get(k2));`

you have predefined map `this.map=map;` but if you add an element, the comparator is called. But as the element is not on the map yet `this.map.get(k1)` returns `null`. That's why you get `null.compareTo(...)` which leads to the exception.

Comment: I appreciate this but I need to understand how I can change teh code so that the TM is sorted after adding a new entry.

Comment: Look, you add key-value param, and compare values instead of keys `map.get(k1).compareTo()`. it is weird. Because map has a requirement to have unique, comparable keys. That's why you have to compare the keys: `k1.compareTo(k2)`. Or, if you really must compare values, think about a different key.